# marklogic nodejs query on sub record of json document

Tags: marklogic

For a document:

```
{
  a: [
    { b: 1, c: 2 },
    { b: 3, c: 2 },
    { b: 1, c: 4 },
  ]
}
```

I want to have document match if (a.b=1 and a.c=2) in the same sub object.

Here, only a[0] match (a.b=1 and a.c=2)

For document:

```
{
  a: [
    { b: 3, c: 2 },
    { b: 1, c: 4 },
  ]
}
```

No match must be the result.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this in the Node.js Client API, but in general terms, I think you need to wrap a [cts:near-query()](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:near-query) in a [cts:element-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query). For the near-query, specify a distance of 1 and use the "ordered" option. I'm not sure about the syntax, but this should get you close:

```
qb.scope(
  'a',
  qb.near(
    qb.value('b', 1),
    qb.value('c', 2),
    1,
    qb.ordered(true)
  )
)
```

Note that you'll need some indexes turned on in order for [unfiltered queries](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_13165) to provide accurate results. For the near queries to work, I'd turn on "element positions" and "element word positions".